# Moving to a new house with my 11 cats

Tags: cats, house-moving

Firstly, I would like to say that I am ecstatically happy to discover such a platform because I’ve been so worried about a problem I am facing and I am in need of your consult.

I have 11 cats in my garden outdoor. They do not enter the house but stay in the garden, they sleep, eat and play! We offer them everything just like a house cats since the day of their birth.
Those cats sometimes also go to the streets but at the end of the day they always sleep in my garden and eat what I put out for them.
They are not used to look for food because every time they are hungry they start making noises and come sit by the windows calling for us to feed them.
Some of the cats are one family (A mother, children, grandsons - if can we call it), and 3 of them are a mother and her children.

The problem is, I am moving to a new house in a couple of days and it all happened so quickly.
It is in a completely different neighborhood that doesn’t resemble the one I live in now.

I really love my cats and think they also need me so I cannot leave them behind for the streets.

I would like to mention that there is garden in the new house and a space for them. But, the environment is so different from the current house once you get out of the house territory.

I have no idea how to move them because they rejects carrying. Also, I do not know if it is the right decision to take them with me.

I have read another questions that may be related but moat of the advisors advised to keep the cats in the house for a while which I cannot do.

Thank you!